# Are these statements about the maximum likelihood estimator and efficiency correct?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, inference, estimators, unbiased-estimator, efficiency

I'm trying to understand efficiency and its relation with maximum likelihood estimators so I need someone to confirm or correct these statements I deduced :

1/ If the maximum likelihood estimator **exists** but **it's not unique** then the estimator is **biased**.

2/ If the maximum likelihood estimator is **biased** then there exists **no efficient estimator**.

3/ If the maximum likelihood **exists** but is **not unique** then there is **no efficient estimator** ( kinda implied by 1 and 2 ).

4/ If an estimator is **efficient** then does that mean it's the **unique** maximum likelihood estimor?

5/ There exists **only one** efficient estimator.

I know that I may have repeated some points but I want to build a clear map in my brain to completely get these once and for all.